# Unexpected behaviour of d3.js Scale / Domain Values

Tags: javascript, d3.js, dns, scale

Apologies but I am ~5 hours into head banging on this and cant work out what is going on. I am playing with some of the examples on the http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock site and trying to add a legend to a stacked bar chart.

To do so I am setting a scale and range:

```
var z = d3.scale.ordinal()
          .range(["#98abc5", "#8a89a6", "#7b6888", "#6b486b", "#a05d56", "#d0743c", "#ff8c00"]);
```

Having loaded the data I am setting the domain:

```
z.domain(d3.keys(datasorted[0]).filter(function(key) { return key !== "xAxisD"; }));
```

If I console log at this point...

```
console.log(z.domain().slice().reverse())
```

... I get what I am expecting, e.g. the keys from the data set:

> ["Scenario 1", "Scenario 2", "Scenario 3"]

I then use the stack layout to amend the data into the correct format:

```
  var layers = d3.layout.stack()(element.map(function(c) {
    return datasorted.map(function(d) {
    return {x: d.xAxisD, y: d[c]};
    });
  }));
```

Following this I append some groups to the already created SVG with styles filled by the colours generated as part of the 'z' scale:

```
var layer = svg.selectAll(".layer")
    .data(layers)
    .enter()
    .append("g")
        .attr("class", "layer")
        .style("fill", function(d, i) {  return z(i) ; });
```

Now when I console log...

```
console.log(z.domain().slice().reverse())
```

... I am getting additional values in my scale:

> [2, 1, 0, "Scenario 1", "Scenario 2", "Scenario 3"]

There are the same amount of additional values as there were scenarios in the data set - e.g. it seems to double the domain.

I cant even seem to phrase the problem in a Google search and so turning to StackOverflow for help please.

Thanks in advance.

Edit - added console log of datasorted:

```
[Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object]
 0: Object
   Strategy 1: 7967144.750000002
   Strategy 2: 1925965.1996200003
   Strategy 3: 198181.8768
   xAxisD: "m01"
   __proto__: Object
 1: Object
 2: Object
 3: Object
etc
```

Answer (score 1):

your problem is here: return z(i)

you should be passing the scenario name ("Scenario 1", "Scenario 2"...) instead of i (0,1,2)

how to get the scenario name? difficult to guess without a working jfiddle or seeing the content of your mapsorted array (or the mapped version of it)

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have added the console log of the datasorted data set. The only issue is that when the data is transformed into the layers variable with the stack() layout it ditches the scenario name data - e.g. they are not in the layers data set, only the original datasorted data. I have added the console log of the datasorted data.

Answer (score 0):

Right, thank you tato, I tried to vote up etc but dont seem to have enough points to do this... (as an aside I spend large amounts of time on StackOverflow and always want to vote up answers that are useful - it would be nice if I could).

tato was essentially correct, I needed to pass the value not the index position of the domain... I was effectively working with a domain value above that was independent of the data set and so couldnt be related to it.

Solution:

Add a value to 'layers' that included the scenario names (Scenario 1, ...)

```
var layers = d3.layout.stack()(element.map(function(c) {
    return datasorted.map(function(d) {
    return {x: d.xAxisD, y: d[c], z: c };
    });
}));
```

Use this to set the domain (rather than the original data set):

```
z.domain(layers.map(function(d, i) { return d[i].z; }));
```

Then use the value from the 'layers' data set to match the domain value when creating the bar colours AND legend:

```
var layer = svg.selectAll(".layer")
        .data(layers)
        .enter()
        .append("g")
            .attr("class", "layer")
            .style("fill", function(d, i) {  return z(d[i].z) ; });

legend.append("rect")
       .attr("x", width - 18)
       .attr("width", 18)
       .attr("height", 18)
       .style("fill", function(d, i) { return z(d); });
```

Basically this is about ensuring the data contains an appropriate reference to the domain as tato said.